# Input box in an HTML file that controls a number in a JS file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS file with a function that looks like this:

```
function Animation(options) {
  defaultOptions = {       
    'direction'         : 'clockwise',         
    'propertyName'      : null,                
    'propertyValue'     : null,                
    'duration'          : 15,                                 
    'repeat'            : null,                                     
    'callbackFinished'  : null,                
    'callbackBefore'    : null,                
    'callbackAfter'     : null,           
  }
  ...
```

...and then it continues onto the rest of the animation, using those values.

Let's say I wanted to have an input box inside of an html file that directly changed one of those values, how would I go about doing that?

I'd just need it to work so if you placed "24" into the input box and pressed a button, it would set 'duration' to 24. Then when you refreshed the .html file and triggered the animation, it would have a duration of 24.

Is this possible? If not, is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: The answer to your question is "yes" it is possible, however there are a few ways to do it depending the circumstances you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can do that !

In my snippet, if you fill the input it will override the default options, but if you let it empty it will keep 15 as defaults.

Hope this helps !

```js
function Animation(options) {
  defaultOptions = {       
    'direction'         : 'clockwise',         
    'propertyName'      : null,                
    'propertyValue'     : null,                
    'duration'          : options.duration || 15,                                 
    'repeat'            : null,                                     
    'callbackFinished'  : null,                
    'callbackBefore'    : null,                
    'callbackAfter'     : null,           
  };
  alert('duration is : ' + defaultOptions.duration);
};

function callAnimation() {
  var input = document.getElementById('animationDuration');
  Animation({duration: input.value});  
};
```

```html
<input type="number" step="1" id="animationDuration">
<button onclick="callAnimation()">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: I have a wheel with two files. wheel.js and index.html. index.html has a script tag in it with all of the code for the wheel that is displayed, and it references wheel.js for instructions on what to do. Since it is on a different file and you have to refresh the page to spin the wheel again, I can't make this work.

Comment: Well the fact that your JavaScript is in a separated file doesn't change anything. I don't really understand your problem here :/ Your function Animation has to be called after the user entered a duration value, otherwise it cannot work. Or do you want the user to change the duration value while the method is being executed ?

Comment: Okay, I added this to my code and kept changing the value after || to see where it went wrong. It looks like even though I input a value and press accept, when I spin the wheel it uses whatever duration is after ||.

Comment: Even when I use the alert to see what it is, if I change it to 3 and click "Confirm" it still outputs 15.

Comment: The use of "option.value || 15" means that it will only use 15 if options.value resolve in a false statement (meaning option.value is undefined or null). So I guess there is a problem when retrieving the value from your input.

Comment: So I've made this: `  alert('duration is : ' + document.getElementById('animationDuration'));` and it returns with this: duration is : [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: So, the issue is with the html part most likely, as when I reference it in the script it can't output anything useful.

Comment: Well this should work fine then, have you tried output "document.getElementById('animationDuration').value" ? Also make sure your input as type="number" to have a number value, not a String. If if still not working you should really provide all of your code because I can't help you more without it.

Comment: Yes the input is a number, not a string. When I add .value to the end of `  alert('duration is : ' + document.getElementById('wheelStopAngle').value);` and it now outputs this: duration is :

Comment: Oh just to clarify, I changed the value to wheelStopAngle because that is what the wheel will finally do, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Yeah so the problem is that your input.value is undefined, that's why it's using the default 15 value. This probably means that your Animation method is called before you enter a value in the input field. You should have a confirm/valid/run button that do your Animation({...}) call after you enter a value.

Comment: Okay, so I fixed it by instead of using your animation line, I used the pre-existing animation of the duration.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to define a constructor, so that it can be instantiated with different settings. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
</head>
<body>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script>
function Animation() {
  this.defaultOptions = {       
    'direction'         : 'clockwise',         
    'propertyName'      : null,                
    'propertyValue'     : null,                
    'duration'          : 15,
    'repeat'            : null,                                     
    'callbackFinished'  : null,                
    'callbackBefore'    : null,                
    'callbackAfter'     : null,           
  }

  // alternative ways to define and access the properties
  var thisAnim = this;
  this.direction = 'clockwise';
  this.propertyName = 'duration';

  this.propertyValue = thisAnim.defaultOptions.duration;
}

function SetAnimDuration(value) {
  // set option value
  myAnim.defaultOptions.duration=value;

  // debugger display
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = myAnim.defaultOptions.duration;
  console.log("duration=", myAnim.propertyValue);
}
var myAnim = new Animation();


</script>
</head>
<body>

Click a button to set the duration:
<br>
  <button id="setDuration" type="button" class="button" onclick="SetAnimDuration('24')">Set Duration to 24</button>
<br>
  <button id="setDuration" type="button" class="button" onclick="SetAnimDuration('35')">Set Duration to 35</button>

<br> Duration: <span id='msg'> N/A </span>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The purpose of the wheel makes it so that we need it to be more flexible than a few buttons. I really just need a way for a variable (one that I declare as an input from some box somewhere) to be spit out instead of a 15 in duration.